# How this Erlang function to do BSL on binaries work?

Tags: binary, erlang, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can someone dumb it down and explain, how this code fragment from a [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390641/erlang-binary-format-bitwise-operations-exist-eg-167f-16ff-bsl-1) works ?

```
bbsl(Bin,Shift) -> <<_:Shift,Rest/bits>> = Bin, <<Rest/bits,0:Shift>>.
```

Comment: thank @Paul-R, for fixing the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bbsl(Bin, Shift) ->     % function accepts binary and number
  << _:Shift,           % match Shift number of bits into dummy variable _ and
     Rest/bits>> = Bin, % puts rest of the bits into Rest variable from Bin variable

  << Rest/bits,         % start creating new binary with bits from Rest at beginning
     0:Shift >>.        % and Shift number of 0's in the end
```

hope that made sense

Comment: Thanks @keymone. Excellent (& truly dumbed-down) explanation. I think I was kind-of confused due to usage of "bits" as type-specifier, as the only ones I was familiar with (slightly) were "binary" and "bitstring". It is as clear as can be.

Comment: to clarify it for you: bits is alias for bitstring, bitstring can represent any number of bits while binary can only represent(and match to) a list of bytes or in other words - any number of bit octets.

Comment: thanks @keymore. I found some more details [here](http://docs.bitbucket.org/erlang_otp/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#bit-syntax-expressions).